# angular observable usage with multiple components

Tags: angular, observable

I have user.service where I call backend API and get some user details
This is how I implement observable thing in service

```
export class UserService {
  private _userDetails: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
```

for external use I declare

```
  public userDetailsObs = this._userDetails.asObservable();
```

then I have backend API function where I store response into

```
 this._userDetails.next(res);
```

Now when I log in I call that function, And it is supposed that from this moment user details will be accessable ewhereywhere. After that press Main page and cannot get user details.

```
this.UserService.userDetailsObs.subscribe((res) =>this.userDetails=res);
```

But if I call API from here also then everything works.

```
this.UserService.apicall();
    this.UserService.userDetailsObs.subscribe((res) =>this.userDetails=res);
```

Problem is that I don't want to call backend API  from each component. I want to call it once and then to use that observable. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `ReplaySubject`, instead of `Subject`, should do the trick (with a vanilla `Subject`, the subscribers who subscribe after last emission don't get fed).

```
_userDetails: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject(1);
```

(Or you could use some state management library, like NGRX, NGXS, but that's a serious change).

Comment: did that, but it does not help :(